# Is there a way to stream call to a remote websocket Server on Freeswitch?

Tags: node.js, websocket, stream, record, freeswitch

I want to stream calls on freeswitch to a node.js websocket server (url: wss//localhost:8755/{callUUID})

The only thing I can find is using mod_shout to stream to an icecast server.

```
<action application="record" data="shout://source:pass@10.10.10.10:8000/stream.mp3"/>
or
conference 3001-10.10.10.10 record shout://source:pass@10.10.10.10:8000/stream.mp3
```

Is there a way to do session_record and stream to the websocket server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are modules :

[**mod_unimrcp**](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_unimrcp)

> mod_unimrcp is the FreeSWITCH module that allows communication with Media Resource Control Protocol (MRCP) servers. MRCP allows client machines to control media resources on a network. MRCP version 1 uses the Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP) while version 2 uses the Session Initiation Protocol (SIP) to negotiate the MRCP connection. mod_unimrcp allows FreeSWITCH to act as such a client. Servers are supplied by numerous vendors such as Cepstral, Voxeo, Nuance, and many others.

[**mod_vlc**](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_vlc)

`<action application="record" data ="vlc://#standard{access=http,mux=raw,dst=localip:someport/somevariable}"/>`

[**mod_rtmp**](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_rtmp)

> mod_rtmp is an RTMP (Real time media protocol) endpoint for FreeSWITCH. The RTMP protocol is primarily used by Flash for streaming audio, video, and data over the Internet.